In mongoengine, how to query the keys in a DictField?
I have data stored in a document that utilizes a Dictfield for storing variable data. What I am trying to do after saving the data is query the field and retrieve any document which contains the key found in the Dictfield. I have tried many different queries, but none seem to pull the data.
class limbs(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField(db_field="limbName")
    swift = IntField(db_field="swift")

class foo(Document):
    name = StringField(db_field="name")
    body_parts = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(limbs), db_field="bodyParts")


entry = foo()
entry.name = "bob"
aa = limbs()
aa.name = "no skill hand"
aa.swift = 5
entry.parts["left arm"] = aa
entry.save()

entry = foo()
entry.name = "jack"
aa = limbs()
aa.name = "the other left foot"
aa.swift = 15

entry.parts["right leg"] = aa
entry.save()

Ideally what I am trying to do is query foo and find all documents which contain "arm" I tried the following but so far I cannot figure it out.
foo.objects(Q(body_parts__keys__contains="arm"))
foo.objects(Q(body_parts__icontains="arm"))
foo.objects(Q(body_parts="arm"))

update:
I have found a way to query for documents that contain the exact name of the key.
foo.objects(Q(**{"body_parts__left_arm__exists":True}))

but this only works with exact key field names. Is there a way to make it look for all that contains the text in the key?
